# Xcode only symbolicates my code

Tags: ios, xcode

I downloaded a .crash file from an iPad.  I imported the file into Xcode.  I know it finds the dSYM file properly because it provides stack information for the code in my application.  However, the function calls in the iOS SDK are not symbolicated.  My hunch is that I don't have the symbols for 32-bit ARM, not sure if that is possible, or how to fix that if so.

```
Hardware Model:      iPad3,6
Process:             MyApp [363]
Identifier:          com.echo.myapp
Version:             2.0 (1.5)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.2 (11D257)

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  10

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation              0x2d5aeec6 0x2d4da000 + 872134
1   libobjc.A.dylib             0x3819ece2 0x3819b000 + 15586
2   CoreData                    0x2d312fcc 0x2d2e5000 + 188364
3   CoreData                    0x2d32171c 0x2d2e5000 + 247580
4   CoreData                    0x2d3214fe 0x2d2e5000 + 247038
5   MyApp                       0x000a88fc -[CIAppDelegate uploadDirtyObjects:] (CIAppDelegate.m:3320)
6   MyApp                       0x000a7d86 -[CIAppDelegate uploadAllChangedData] (CIAppDelegate.m:3204)
7   MyApp                       0x00096bec -[CIAppDelegate sync] (CIAppDelegate.m:1176)
8   Foundation                  0x2df98a0a 0x2decb000 + 842250
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib     0x387ba954 0x387b8000 + 10580
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib     0x387ba8c6 0x387b8000 + 10438
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib     0x387b8ae4 0x387b8000 + 2788
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a device with the armv7s or arm64 chip running iOS 7.1.2 and connect it to your Mac so Xcode can import the symbols it needs to symbolicate these calls.

Comment: Apple doesn't provide a site where I can download them?  This is from a client's iPad, I don't have access to it.

Comment: No, they don't provide that.